# X dimension of text object reported inconsistently

Tags: python, text-object, dimensions

I'm running Blender 2.79 on Windows 10 and came across what seems to be an inconsistency in the **bpy** library behavior. I run the code from a Text Editor screen. The code prints to the system console, so you'll have to open ("toggle") it from the top Windows menu.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.text_add(radius=7, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
obj = bpy.data.objects['Text']
obj.data.body = 'Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

#bpy.ops.object.text_add(radius=7, location=(0, -20, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=32, radius=10, 
#    depth=10, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))

print(str(bpy.data.objects['Text'].dimensions.x))
```

When running the code as is, the value printed to the console - the "length" of the text object - is **13.28**. Change the content of the text object to something much shorter (for example 'I') and something much longer ('HERE GOES OUR TOP TEXT') and run the code sample again for each scenario. The value printed to the console is still **13.28**. In fact, it will be the same **regardless** of the contents of the text object.

Now comment out the line that creates a second text object. The value printed to the console becomes 67.94, and it will vary (as expected) as you shorten or lengthen the contents of the (first) text object.
If you comment back the line creating the second text object then the value printed will revert to 13.28 regardless of the contents of the text object.

Since the behavior is puzzling, I tried some more. Comment out the line creating the second text object and un-comment the two lines that create a cylinder. The x dimension of the text object is now reported correctly.

It seems that if I create a **single** text object then I can't get an accurate measure of its x size ("length"), since it's always the same. But if I add any **other arbitrary object** ***after*** creating the text object then the text object's length is reported correctly.
Note: this happens only in the Text Editor screen (which is where I need to run my real, much-larger script from) - in the Python console the x dimension of any text object is reported correctly, but that doesn't really do much for me, since I can't run this script one line at a time.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Is this a bug that needs to be reported? Or is it caused by my misunderstanding of some mysterious behavior of the four simple lines of code?
(This is not a theoretical issue - I'm trying to automate a process that is very sensitive to the length of various text objects, and not being able to measure them at all means pretty much game over for this exercise.)

Comment: Getting the same behavior here, only after second run do I get correct values. Not much of a scripter myself, but sounds like a bug

Comment: Requires an update, `scene.update()` for 2.7x and prior.  `obj.data.update_tag()` will ensure the font is updated when scene is next updated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it when I get back in town.